# update SQLite with content of push notification when the app is not running

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

Is there a way to update SQLite as soon as  the push notification is received but the app is not running currently(or the app was killed).

If the notification arrives when the app is running or in background -
"didReceiveRemoteNotification" method handles my update.

If the notification arrives when the app is not running I want to update the content of push notification to my sqlite. The update works when the user taps on the notification but it doesn't work when the user taps on the app icon.
Please help. Thank you.

Comment: There is no way to do that. Notifications are handled by iOS itself. If app would be handling this, there might be some way to get this figured out. I've been wasting my time over it but didn't succeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no way to update the database without tapping. But if your app is using background modes like VOIP or location updates as mentioned in the apple doc, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Then it might wake your app on certain duration and do the update part.

**EDIT**

By the way when a Push notification arrives, the server should also be updated, I dont think Push notifications is a good way to update your database. Instead of that You should make a call to your server to get the latest local happenings and then update to your sqlite. You can perform this in didFinishLaunching or didEnterForeground. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Thank you Rajan for the answer. I will go with your suggestion.